# Can flink connect address be load balanced when connecting to NebulaGraph Database?

Tags: nebula-graph

There is an issue connecting to the Nebula Graph cluster with flink connector: `GraphAddress` and `MetaAddress`:

```
NebulaClientOptions nebulaClientOptions =
                new NebulaClientOptions.NebulaClientOptionsBuilder()
                        .setGraphAddress("127.0.0.1:9669")
                        .setMetaAddress("127.0.0.1:9559")
                        .build();
```

1.Can I fill in more than one graph and meta address?

2.If multiple addresses are supported, what is the proper way to fill them? Is the access order of different nodes random or sequential?

3.If only one is written, will the cluster be automatically load-balanced?

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include some more popular tags and/or language tags so more people will see your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can fill more than 3 metad addresses and graphd addresses. Just as below:

```
setGraphAddress (“ip1:port1,ip2:port2”)
```

Notice: the address access is random.

If you has a cluster, but configuration has only one meta address then the system will not be automatically load-balanced.